# Elementary Matrices Confusion

Tags: linear-algebra

"Consider the following 3 row operations performed to a 4×3 matrix A used to transform it into a matrix B: −1R1+R2→R2, R2↔R4, 16R1→R1. The transformation can be accomplished by applying elementary matrices to A. Let E1 be the elementary matrix corresponding to −1R1+R2→R2, let E2 correspond to R2↔R4, and E3 correspond to 16R1→R1. Then B=PA where P=E3E2E1."

I don't understand why $E_1$ is: 
$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ -1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$

Shouldn't the first elementary matrix be a $4$x$3$ matrix? I don't understand how we are getting a $4$x$4$ matrix.

---

I found this: http://www.physicsforums.com/showthread.php?t=530916 which explains my question, but I do not understand it.

Comment: @Amzoti No. I am not givin the actual matrix $A$. I am just told its a 4x4. I don't think we need the original matrix anyway.

Comment: With what kind of matrix do you have to left-multiply a 4x3-matrix to again get a 4x3-matrix?

Comment: Do you understand matrix multiplication? Have you calculated an example of $E_1A$?

Comment: Ah I think I understand. Because we have the definition: $E_k * E_{k-1} * E_{k-2} * \cdots * E_1 * A = B$, this means that $B$ must remain the same compisition as $A$. Thus, the elementary matrices be  composition that ensures that. A 4x4 matrix.

Answer (score 0):

The product of a $n\times m$ matrix and a $m\times p$ matrix is a $n\times p$ matrix. Therefore, the elementary matrices have to be $4 \times 4$ matrices to ensure the size of the matrix $A$ does not change on left multiplication.

When you multiply a matrix $A=\begin{pmatrix}a_1& a_2 & a_3 \end{pmatrix}$, where $a_i$ are column vectors of $A$, on the left by a matrix $E$, the product is a matrix $EA=\begin{pmatrix}E a_1 & E a_2 & E a_3\end{pmatrix}$. You can try multiplying the vector $a=\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\\w\end{pmatrix}$ by an elementary matrix of your choice and see what happens.